# free the NETBIOS name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, administration, windows-server-2019

I need to configure Windows server 2019 several times on a single VM and promote it as a DC in a new forest in a domain name, for example "new.det". I am using a powershell script for this, and I have the following problem: after the first installation, I use the snapshot and run the script again on a clean VM, I get the error "NetBIOS name  is already in use". How can I solve this problem if I don't want to change the NetBIOS name and any other settings? I can't figure out where the NetBIOS name information is stored. There is no other vms in domain or my network. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What PowerShell script? The error "NetBIOS name is already in use" seems pretty clear. The NetBIOS name is generally the name of the computer (up to 15 characters).

Comment: If you have cloned the VM you must set a new name on the clone.  Windows does not allow duplicate computer names on the network.  Run `hostname` on each VM and ensure they are different.  Use `Rename-Computer -NewName foo` to set a new name.

Answer (score 0):

That was my fault, I set the server name and then tried to install ADDC with the server name as netbios for new domain. Therefore, there was a conflict.